# How to implement in Kotlin Native FileSeek, getFileLength and readIntoBuffer?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

How to correctly implement these features for Kotlin Native/iOS? I'm trying to implement file reading for DFU utility and it is not working.

iOS Implementation:

```
actual class PlatformFile actual constructor(val filePath: String) {

    private val platformFile = NSFileHandle.fileHandleForReadingAtPath(filePath)

    actual fun setPosition(start: Long) {
        platformFile!!.seekToFileOffset(start.toULong())
    }

    actual fun getLength(): Long {
        val fileSize = NSFileManager.defaultManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath,null) as NSDictionary
        return fileSize.fileSize().toLong()
        }

    actual fun readIntoBuffer(buffer: ByteArray): Int {
        val read = platformFile!!.readDataOfLength(buffer.size.toULong())
        buffer = read.toByteArray()
        return read.length.toInt()
    }
}
```

Common Implementation:

```
expect class PlatformFile(filePath: String) {
    /**
     * Sets the file-pointer offset, measured from the beginning of this
     * file, at which the next read or write occurs.
     */
    fun setPosition(start: Long)
    fun getLength(): Long
    /**
     * Reads up to {@code buffer.length} bytes of data from this file
     * into an array of bytes.
     * @param      buffer   the buffer into which the data is read.
     * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
     *             {@code -1} if there is no more data because the end of
     *             this file has been reached.
     */
    fun readIntoBuffer(buffer: ByteArray): Int
}
```

Android Implementation(Working Implementation):

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile
actual class PlatformFile actual constructor(filePath: String) {
    private val platformFile = RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r")
    actual fun setPosition(start: Long) = platformFile.seek(start)
    actual fun getLength(): Long = platformFile.length()
    actual fun readIntoBuffer(buffer: ByteArray): Int = platformFile.read(buffer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is it not working? Compiler error, runtime error, or simply not doing what you expect? An error message / stack trace would help.

Also, have you considered using Okio? It's partly multiplatform, including the filesystem portion.

https://square.github.io/okio

Comment: Aside of compile error when trying reassing buffer with read it doesn't work like android implementation.

Comment: Okio's filesystem is nowhere near multiplatform, they don't even have an implementation for iOS filesytem as you can see in the source code.